# Problem during ubuntu installation: Realtek PXE always boots instead?

Tags: boot, system-installation, realtek, pxe

I am trying to install ubuntu on my Toshiba Satellite by booting it from a USB. I was eventually able to get the installer to load; I had to change my boot mode to CSM *and* use a specific USB port for whatever reason. The ubuntu installer was working fine, but my friend noticed during installation that I hadn't partitioned my hard drive correctly. I decided to quit the installer, with the intention of loading Windows to fix the partition problem.

However, when I quit the installer a black screen appeared that persisted for several minutes. In frustration I did a hard shut off, which in retrospect was a bad decision: now, my Realtek PXE will always boot first, no matter what I do!

For example, if I start my computer and press F12, a menu of devices I can boot from appears. Already there is a problem: the names of the devices are usually messed up. For example, my USB might be called Realtek PXE and my ODD might be called SanDisk! The only device whose name is always correct is the hard drive.

No matter which device I select to boot, and no matter whether the names are correct or not, my Realtek PXE will boot instead. If I go into BIOS settings and change the boot order, PXE will still boot instead. In order to load windows, I have to change boot mode to UEFI and boot my hard drive. PXE still boots instead, but the screen says `PXE over IPv4. Press ENTER to exit.` (That may not be the exact wording.) If I press ENTER a few times, Windows will load.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I know that this isn't an ubuntu question per se, but this issue came about during ubuntu installation so perhaps someone has had the same problem before.

Comment: PXE boot is likely first in your BIOS / Boot Order - have you changed this yet?  (Might show as Netowrk Boot or similar in your boot order screens)

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, I made sure that PXE is last in my boot order. The first option is either my USB or my Hard Drive. Actually, interestingly enough, order doesn't stay fixed. Even if I don't change the boot order, sometimes my hard drive will go above my USB, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problem has resolved itself, though I'm not sure how. I literally kept trying to boot from my USB over and over and eventually it worked, though I didn't change anything. I'm actually typing this from ubuntu now!

I'll update this question if things go south again.